# AutoMagic select box not populating in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I've got the following relationship set-up between two models

- Story belongsTo StoryType
- StoryType hasMany Story

I've set-up a form to select the StoryType for each story using the following code:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Story.story_type_id', array('tabindex' => 2));
```

with this code in the controller to populate the list

```
$this->set('story_types', $this->Story->StoryType->find('list', array ('order' => 'title')));
```

**But it's not populating the select box with anything.** I know that the find() option is working because doing a debug within the controller produces this:

```
Array
(
    [1] => First Person
    [3] => Third Person
)
```

The weird thing is that it's exactly the same code, just querying other models, to populate select lists for things like users and genres, it's just the story types that isn't working.

Any ideas? Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't mention which version of CakePHP you're using, but try setting `storyTypes` rather than `story_types`:

```
$this->set( 'storyTypes', $this->Story->StoryType->find( 'list', array( 'order' => 'title' ) ) );
```

Older versions of CakePHP (pre-1.3) modified set variable names to headlessCamelCase and, even if you're using 1.3.x, there may be a little bit of that infrastructure lingering. It's a bit of a reach, but it's easy enough to test and it seems *plausible* that this could be the root of your problem.

I'll be curious to see what you find out.

Comment: I'm using 1.3(.4 I think), and your solution worked great - one question however, does this mean that it's likely to change as I upgrade cake?

Comment: It might. Given what you've found, it seems like they've made the right decision, but haven't carried it all the way through yet (read: possible bug). The decision to modify from underscore notation to headlessCamelCase is a legacy one (and a bad one, IMO). They've stopped the modification in the `set()` method itself, but they may not have found all of the ripples. Take a look at this article (http://archive.robwilkerson.org/2008/12/28/cakephp-watch-out-for-the-compact-function/index.html) and Nate Abele's (former dev lead) comment.

Comment: if this is truly happening still in 1.3 i would stick a ticket on lighthouse. I've been using 1.3 since it was beta and never had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little hacky, but I think it will work:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Story.story_type_id', array('tabindex' => 2, 'options' => $story_types));
```

Comment: That would work, I guess, but the correct solution is the other one.

Answer (score 1):

here's what you should really do .. (esp, for version 2.x) - in case if some people are facing the same problem.

[inside your constroller action]

```
$oneOfTheColumns = 'title'; //just for sake of making it clear - if you have to order the results

$storyTypes = $this->Story->StoryType('find', array('order'=>$oneOfTheColumns));
$this->set(compact('storyTypes'));
```

[inside your view]

```
echo $this->Form->input('StoryType');
```